# iOS8 UISplitViewController's display mode button behavior

Tags: ios, ios8, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a problem in iOS8 when I have multiple detail views in `UISplitViewController`, the problem comes only in **horizontally compact mode**.

My storyboard looks similar to this:
[image]

As you can see, my master's table has two types of cells, each one is connected to "its own" hierarchy of detail views using **Show Detail** segue. So clicking first cell will load D1 (and its root) in secondary area of split view, clicking the second cell will load D2 there.

I am adding the split view's super smart display mode button to any detail's navigation item when preparing for segue:

```
controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem;
controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = YES;
```

Everything works perfect except one case:

- I am in horizontally compact size (for example, iPhone 6 portrait)
- Secondary area is shown, for example D1 screen. Primary is hidden.
- On some occasion (like a button click in D1) I want to load D2 in the secondary area. I call `performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDetailD2"...` to load it.

Now once I do that my magic display mode button shows "<D1" and clicking it goes back to D1! That is **totally not** the behavior that I want. This kind of 'history' back is desirable when I am navigating **inside** D1 or D2 itself (and I believe this button is smart enough to do that). But when I am on the top level, I want it to open the primary area. Basically I need more something like a left drawer opener (like in Android).

**Rationale:** My D1 is expressing some kind of error/incomplete state (no connection/ no user / etc) and when the state is 'fixed' then the 'normal' UI is loaded through D2 or D3 or any other. It is really strange to see a back button to an error page at this point. This history feature is even good when I go from D2 to D3, so if there is a way to somehow remove D1 from history - that will also help me.

In worst case I would do the button logic on my own - I would need a way to open the drawer (primary area), that info will also help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after struggling for a while, I found a way to get what I need. It comes out that in collapsed mode the split view "becomes" just a simple navigation controller under the hood. So there is a parent navigation controller on top of D2 (which is also a navigation controller). The code below written in `viewDidLoad` of the **root controller of D2** does the trick:

```
UINavigationController* parentNavi = self.navigationController.navigationController;
if (parentNavi != nil) {
    // will get here only in collapsed mode
    NSMutableArray *controllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:parentNavi.viewControllers];
    NSMutableIndexSet *set = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSet];
    for (UIViewController *controller in controllers) {
        if ([controller.title isEqualToString:@"D1"]) {
            [set addIndex:[controllers indexOfObject:controller]];
        }
    }
    [controllers removeObjectsAtIndexes:set];
    parentNavi.viewControllers = controllers;
}
```

The code will enter the `if` statement only when you are in compact sizes. After cleaning up the controllers the display mode button points to the primary area. This code is also quite flexible - you can get rid of any page you don't need in stack.